# Undefined symbol when using C++ source for f2py

Tags: python, c++, c, f2py

I can wrap a C function with `f2py` as follows:

> foo.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(int n, int * a) {
    printf("%d\n", n);
}
```

The corresponding interface file is

> foo.pyf

```
python module foo
interface
subroutine func(n, a)
    intent(c) func
    intent(c)

    integer, intent(hide)                  :: n = shape(a,0)
    real(kind=8), dimension(n), intent(in) :: a
end subroutine func
end interface
end python module foo
```

Then, I execute, `f2py foo.pyf -c foo.c -m foo`, which creates the Python library, and so for example, the code

```
import numpy as np
import foo

foo.func( np.ones(3) )
```

prints `3` as you would expect.

### Problem: changing `foo.c` → `foo.cpp` results in undefined symbol

By changing the extension of `foo.c` to `foo.cpp`, I notice that

```
f2py foo.pyf -c foo.cpp -m foo
```

calls `g++` instead of `gcc`. Fine. However, afterwards when I execute, `import foo` in Python, I see:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: ./foo.so: undefined symbol: func_
```

What magic must I apply to make `f2py` work with C++ code? Is it possible?

**Additional note:**

If I remove the line `intent(c) foo` in the interface file, then the `foo.c` yields the same behavior, i.e., it compiles with `f2py` gives the same undefined symbol error when import from Python.

Comment: Why, exactly, are you trying to generate Python bindings for ***C*** (and C++) functions via `f2py`?  This program is for generating bindings for *Fortran* functions.

Comment: The [getting started guide](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/f2py/getting-started.html) indicates that it can be used for both C and Fortran. See [this also](https://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/Cookbook/f2py_and_NumPy.html) (although somewhat dated).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, this is almost certainly an issue with name mangling.

C++ names are held in the linker with much more complex "mangled" names than their "C" counterparts in order to distinguish the overloaded names that C++ allows even for non-class functions.

You can declare a function as `extern "C"` so that it is exported using the C naming convention. The body of the function can still use c++ features, but it should then be visible to f2py, or similar.

Note that this stops you from using C++ name overloading on that function name.

Comment: Yes, this works. Thanks. I added `extern "C"` before `void func ...` in `foo.cpp`.

Comment: Of course, if you can find a cpp2py, that would be better going forward.